# Devise Loses the Username on Failed Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

A huge pet peeve of mine is when I mess up a login, and the page comes back with the username (email or whatever) blank. This crappy user experience is even worse on mobile.

Upon failed login Devise does a redirect back to login, and the username is lost.  Yuck.

Is there a simple way to hook into Devise to retain the username on the form after the redirect?